# xmpp server component error

Tags: xmpp, components, whack

I am developing a simple xmpp server component,while I have been stucked by a little error for few days.After searching and trying all the solution,nothing gets improved. Some of the solutions did not work at all,others can not express how to fix it exactly.So helpless am I that I decide to ask this question by myself.

I use the Whack and Tinder as the externalcomponent library,everything works fine except this error cause by this code :ExternalComponentManager mgr = new ExternalComponentManager

That is the error :
   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/xmpp/component/Log
   at Main.main(Main.java:10)
   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.xmpp.component.Log

The instantiation of the ExternalComponentManager require the log class,which shoule be located in the Tinder library,but the tinder library has no more include this class.So ,how to fix this error ,is anything  I have miss ? by the way,I have refrence the SVN of the whack and add all the jar files in my project classpath . I hope someone can help me  to solve me ,Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please use tinder 1.2.2 version. org.xmpp.component.Log has been removed in tinder 1.2.3 version. I had the same issue and downgraded the tinder jar to 1.2.2 which solved it. The whack jar version used is 1.0.0